# Prove the formula for the inner product of the covariant derivative $\langle \nabla_X Y,Z\rangle$

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I have to prove the following formula:
$$\langle \nabla_X Y,Z\rangle=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_X\langle Y,Z\rangle+\partial_Y\langle Z,X\rangle-\partial_Z\langle X,Y\rangle+\langle Z,[X,Y]\rangle+\langle Y,[Z,X]\rangle-\langle X,[Y,Z]\rangle)$$

I start by computing the differential of the covariant derivative:
\begin{align*}
\partial_X \langle Y, Z \rangle &= \langle\nabla_X Y,Z\rangle + \langle Y,\nabla_X Z \rangle \\
\partial_Y \langle Z, X \rangle &= \langle\nabla_Y Z,X\rangle + \langle Z,\nabla_Y X \rangle \\
-\partial_Z \langle X, Y \rangle &= -\langle\nabla_Z X,Y\rangle - \langle X,\nabla_Z Y \rangle 
\end{align*}
by adding up the above equations, we get
\begin{align*}
\partial_X\langle Y,Z\rangle + \partial_Y\langle Z,X\rangle - \partial_Z\langle X,Y \rangle &= \langle Y,\nabla_X Z-\nabla_Z X\rangle + \langle X,\nabla_Y Z-\nabla_Z Y \rangle + \langle Z,\nabla_X Y+ \nabla_Y X \rangle
\end{align*}
then, using the fact that the torsion is zero and considering $\nabla_X Y + \nabla_Y X = 2\nabla_X Y + \nabla_Y X - \nabla_X Y$ in the last right term, we get
\begin{align*}
\partial_X\langle Y,Z\rangle + \partial_Y\langle Z,X\rangle - \partial_Z\langle X,Y \rangle &=\langle Y,[X,Z]\rangle + \langle X,[Y,Z] \rangle - \langle Z,[X,Y] \rangle + 2\langle Z,\nabla_X Y \rangle
\end{align*}
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\langle \nabla_X Y, Z \rangle &= \dfrac{1}{2}\bigg( \partial_X\langle Y,Z\rangle + \partial_Y\langle Z,X\rangle - \partial_Z\langle X,Y \rangle - \langle X,[Y,Z] \rangle -\langle Y,[X,Z]\rangle + \langle Z,[X,Y] \rangle \bigg)
\end{align*}

However, I get a different a different sign on the 5th element (i.e. $\langle Y,[X,Z]\rangle$) on the RHS. Can somebody suggest where I made a mistake?

Comment: you mean the 5th term? if so, the lie bracket is anticommutative.

Comment: Yes, corrected!

Comment: I'm confused. The original has $\langle Y,[Z,X]\rangle$ and you have $-\langle Y, [X,Z]\rangle$. These are equal.

Comment: @TedShifrin I read Do Carmo's again! You are right! Thanks for pointing it out.